# How add LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/my/path and my binary PATH to .bashrc whenver i install my rpm package(add) and remove my package(remove)

Tags: linux, bash, rpm

```
Name:           my package
Version:        1.0.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        My first rpm package.
License:        Apache License, Version 2.0
Source0:        %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
Prefix:         /opt/my-path
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}

%description
Testing the package


%prep
%setup -q


%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{prefix}
cp %{_sourcedir}/libaws-cpp-sdk-s3.so %{buildroot}/%{prefix}
cp %{_sourcedir}/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so %{buildroot}/%{prefix}
cp %{_sourcedir}/libuv.so.1 %{buildroot}/%{prefix}
cp -R * %{buildroot}/%{prefix}

%post


%preun


%clean
rm -rf %{buildroot}

%files
%{prefix}/%{name}
%{prefix}/libaws-cpp-sdk-s3.so
%{prefix}/libaws-cpp-sdk-core.so
%{prefix}/libuv.so.1

%changelog
* Tue Sep 19 2023 Author: test - 1.0.0
- Initial rpm package release
```

#### **I want to create system variable using my rpm package..**

#### **lets' say  when i install my package it should create two path**

```
1. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/my/shared/library/path2. export PATH=$PATH:/my/binary/path in .bashrc
```

#### when i remove the package it remove these two line from .bashrc

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem: You usually use a text editor to modify your .bashrc. If you are frequently adding and removing packages, it could be a bit easier in maintenance, to put that `export` statement into a separate file (say `set_lib.sh`) and include it from your .bashrc with `[[ -f set_lib.sh ]] && source set_lib.sh`. If you want to temporarily disable this (because the package has been removed), you do a `mv set_lib.sh set_lib.sh-disabled` and don't have to touch your .bashrc. You can re-enable it with another `mv` .

Answer (score 0):

Your package should create a file in `/etc/profile.d`. The default `/etc/bashrc` and `/etc/profile` scripts both source all files in this directory. For example, the `gawk` and `less` packages both use this mechanism.

---

However: if you're building and installing an RPM, you shouldn't *need* to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You should just install your shared libraries into standard directories.